# Unable to connect to SQL Cloud Instance in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I just created a 2nd gen My SQL instance in GCP. I used the below command in the console to connect to the sql instance but I'm getting permissions error.

```
gcloud beta sql connect instance-name --user=root
```

> You need the [cloud_sql_proxy] component to use the `sql connect`
>   command.
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.sql.connect) You cannot perform this action
>   because you do not have permission to modify the Google Cloud SDK
>   installation directory [/google/google-cloud-sdk].

Answer (score 2):

I have tested the command and it is giving me the same error. After that I removed the `beta` and run the command `gcloud sql connect instance-name --user=root`.

I got the following message:

> Whitelisting your IP for incoming connection for 5 minutes...done.
>
> Connecting to database with SQL user [root].Enter password:

So try removing the `beta` from the command.